# ckeditor убирает {}

Tags: wysiwyg, ckeditor

Как заставить CKEDITOR игнорировать некоторые символы?
Например, в тексте у меня встречается {VARNAME}, но редактор ее удаляет, вставляя вместо нее

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно документации [htmlEncodeOutput](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-htmlEncodeOutput):

> Whether to escape HTML when the editor updates the original input element.
>
> config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;

Может быть и не прокатит, отпишитесь.

Comment: не то. =/ Это эскейп всех энтитей, на сколько я понял из описания. А надо, чтобы он сохранял только определенные конструкции, причем без кодирования в энтити. То есть, плейнтекстом

Comment: Знаете, я сейчас скачал последнюю версию редактора, попробовал добавить текст с вашими конструкциями вида {...} и знаете: у меня они не удаляются и не превращаются в мнемоники. Вот пример: http://pastebin.com/wEkC773N скачать сам редактор можете на официальном сайте.